# Concepts - how to constrain integral template value

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

There is a template definition like:

```
template<size_t N>
void foo( void ) {
  /* ... */
}
```

How to define a concept so that `N` must be non-zero positive value (N >= 1)?

Something like:

```
template<size_t N>
concept NonZeroSize = /* to be implemented, N>=1 */

template<NonZeroSize N>
void foo( void ) {
  /* Do whatever only if N >= 1 */
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
template <size_t N> requires NonZeroSize<N>
void foo();
```

Or just:

```
template <size_t N> requires (N > 0)
void foo();
```

The terser form is reserved for type concepts.

---

The concept definition itself is just an arbitrary boolean expression:

```
template <size_t N>
concept NonZeroSize = (N > 0);
```

A [*requires-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req) is just a special kind of expression that's very useful in defining concepts, but it neither *has* to be used in all concept definitions nor *must* it appear in a concept definition to begin with. These things are orthogonal.

Comment: How to define the concept NonZeroSize itself?

Comment: @MartinKopecký The concept definition just takes a boolean expression.

Comment: @MartinKopecký, To put it more directly, `template <size_t N> concept NonZeroSize = N != 0;`. The `requires` you normally see there is just a regular boolean expression.

Comment: @chris In this case GCC complains ‘NonZeroSize’ does not constrain a type...

Comment: @MartinKopecký [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/AUAcp8). Do you have an example?

Comment: @Barry: I have extended your test code https://godbolt.org/z/yaEkUh and it reports the same issue there...

Comment: @MartinKopecký Yeah, you can't do that. Like I said in the answer, the terser form is reserved for type concepts. You have to use a requires clause.